# Обмен данными контроллер-сервис-директива

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angular-directive

Сервис:

```
angular.module('frame-data-storage', [])
    .service('frameDataStorage', frameDataStorage);

frameDataStorage.$inject = [];

function frameDataStorage() {
    var _logo = '',
        _category = '',
        _pinfo = '';
    return {
        setLogo: function (logo) {
            _logo = logo;
        },
        setCat: function (category) {
            _category = category;
        },
        setProviderInfo: function (pinfo) {
            _pinfo = 'dsdsdsaf443';
        },
        getLogo: function () {
            return _logo;
        },
        getCat: function () {
            return _category;
        },
        setProviderInfo: function () {
            return _pinfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Кусок контроллера с которого данные нужно передать

```
   /*data to service*/
        frameDataStorage.setLogo($scope.searchServices.icon);
        frameDataStorage.setCat($scope.categoryName);
        frameDataStorage.setProviderInfo($scope.providerInfo);
    /*end data to service*/
```

И директива в которую хочу передать

```
angular.module('navigation.frameNavBottom', [])
    .directive('frameNavBottom', ['frameDataStorage', function(frameDataStorage) {
        return {
            template: require('./templates/index.html'),
            link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller, $translate, frameDataStorage) {
                $scope.logo = frameDataStorage.getProviderInfo();
            }
        }
    }

]);

module.exports = 'navigation.frameNavBottom';
```

И еще одна

```
var app = angular.module('navigation.frameNavTop');
app.directive('frameNavTop', ['$window', frameNavTop]);

function frameNavTop($window) {
    return {
        template: require('../templates/header.html'),
        controller: ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$document', 'Authentication', 'Bills', 'frameDataStorage', Ctrl],
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    };

    function Ctrl($rootScope, $scope, $state, $document, Authentication, Bills, frameDataStorage) {
        $scope.state = $state;
        $scope.preLoader = false;
        $scope.sliderFormPreLoader = false;
        $scope._sliderFormActive = '';
        $scope.isAuth = false;
        $scope.billsNum = 0;

        /*service frameDataStorage*/
        $scope.logo = frameDataStorage.getLogo();
        /*end service frameDataStorage*/

        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#payment-logo img").clone().appendTo("#service-logo-block");
        }, 2500);

        $scope.goTop = function () {

            if($state.current.name == 'pages.main') {
                $document.scrollTopAnimated(0);

            }
        };
    }

}

module.exports = app;
```

Пока что решил с ней вопрос таким путем

```
setTimeout(function(){
            /*service frameDataStorage*/
            $scope.logo = frameDataStorage.getLogo();
            console.log('logo',$scope.logo);//TODO: delete
            /*end service frameDataStorage*/
        }, 2500);
```

Проблема в том что в них данные передать не удается. В обычный контроллер другой, все отлично срабатывает, в сервисе данные хранятся. Но в директивах пишет

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getProviderInfo' of undefined

Comment: в функцию link Не внедряются зависимости. У нее _строгий_ набор параметров. Зависимости можно добавлять в объявление директивы, что у тебя сделано, например тут `.directive('frameNavBottom', ['frameDataStorage', function(frameDataStorage) {` убрав `frameDataStorage` из параметров `link` эта часть должна заработать

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev, здесь это не имеет значения

Comment: со второй директивой тоже разобрался, добавил таймаут. потому что сначала директива тянула с сервиса а потом в контроллре выполналась запись данных в сервис. но это как по мне костыль. как это исправить? чего то с асинхронностью?

Comment: Не понял про вторую директиву, но jquery и setTimeout в контроллере обычно не нужны

Comment: убрал. теперь другая ошибка TypeError: frameDataStorage.getProviderInfo is not a function

Comment: _TypeError: frameDataStorage.getProviderInfo is not a function_ - что абсолютно логично, потому что в сервисе _frameDataStorage_ действительно нет этой функции. Там есть только _getLogo_ и _getCat_

Comment: а все из-за того, что дважды объявлено свойство _setProviderInfo_

Comment: тфу. точно) опечаточка. спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в функцию `link` **Не** внедряются зависимости.

У нее строгий набор параметров.

```
link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controllers)
```

Зависимости можно добавлять в объявление директивы, что у тебя сделано, например тут

```
.directive('frameNavBottom', ['frameDataStorage', function(frameDataStorage) {
```

убрав frameDataStorage из параметров link эта часть должна заработать

```
.directive('frameNavBottom', ['frameDataStorage', function(frameDataStorage) {
    return {
        template: require('./templates/index.html'),
        link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
            $scope.logo = frameDataStorage.getProviderInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Кроме этого, в `frameDataStorage` возвращается объект *без* метода `getProviderInfo`, но с двумя `setProviderInfo`.

---

Как правило, использование `setTimeout` и `jquery` непосредственно в контроллере добавляют больше хлопот, чем помогают что-то решить, поэтому стоит пересмотреть их использование в этом месте

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#payment-logo img").clone().appendTo("#service-logo-block");
}, 2500);
```

Comment: этот кусов вобще убрал. Было временныр решение. спасибо

Comment: можете подсказать как сделать что бы данные загружаись когда нужно? а то получается при первой загрузке страници данные уходят в сервис и только после перезагрузки выводятся во вьюшке. даже таймаут не спасает

Comment: @Maxim, стоит задать отдельный вопрос, с минимальным примером кода, желательно рабочим. Не совсем понимаю о какой перезагрузке идет речь и как вообще получаются и используются, в том числе во view данные и сервис